# django query running forever and not timing out

Tags: python, mysql, django, gunicorn

I have some django applications that is killing my mysql server
there are queries that are running and not timing out and clogging my mysql server

Just need help on how to resolve this issue the proper way
not sure if this is how django is designed or i need to add a timeout settings
i thought django should do this by default, not sure because makes zero sense to have this with no timeout

Here are the queries that are not timing out or closing

```
MySQL on localhost (5.7.19)                                                                                                                                                                                     load 5.27 4.81 4.69 4/2383 41852 up 0+00:18:41 [19:13:16]
 Queries: 8.6k     qps:    8 Slow:     0.0         Se/In/Up/De(%):    61/01/02/00
 Sorts:      0 qps now:    5 Slow qps: 0.0  Threads:   99 (  99/   1) 44/00/00/00
 Key Efficiency: 98.9%  Bps in/out: 839.8/22.3k   Now in/out: 566.3/22.5k

       Id      User         Host/IP         DB       Time    Cmd    State Query
       --      ----         -------         --       ----    ---    ----- ----------
        6 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db       1096  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:44:56'
        9 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db       1086  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:45:09'
       11 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db       1085  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:45:10'
       15 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db       1067  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:45:28'
       16 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db       1056  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:45:39'
       20 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db       1053  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:45:42'
       25 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db       1037  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:45:58'
       28 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db       1025  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:46:11'
       29 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db       1022  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:46:14'
       32 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db       1006  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:46:29'
       35 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db        994  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:46:42'
       36 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db        990  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:46:45'
```

This is just a copy of what i currently have, those queries keeps on running for a long time and till i restart mysql server and they start again and keep running and eventually they clog up cpu and i/o on the server

What do i do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: it seems about session expiration parameter. Which django version are you using. what is your SESSION_COOKIE_AGE in the settings file. which middlewares are installed

Comment: `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 60*60*24*365*5
SESSION_ENGINE = 'webapp.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True`

Comment: @binboavetonik that is what i have

Comment: `# 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',`
`'webapp.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',`
`# 'django.contrib.sessions',`
`'sessions',`

Comment: anyone willing to help here?